# Unable to run "rails g" commands in docker cli

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am unable to run rails g commands in the docker CLI.

It is throwing the following error, even though everything is already installed and running.

```
Could not find rake-12.3.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

rails db:create and rails db:migrate are fine.

I have tried running the commands from inside the docker CLI and via docker-compose run, and they throw the same error.

My dockerfile, named Dockerfile.dev is as follows

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM ruby:2.6.2-stretch
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs postgresql-client
WORKDIR /app
COPY Gemfile /app/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /app/Gemfile.lock
RUN gem install bundler && bundle install
RUN rails db:create db:migrate

# Add a script to be executed every time the container starts.
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 3000

# Configure the main process to run when running the image
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

My docker-compose file as as follows

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    image: project-x-image-annotator:v1
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Another development is that I have 2 copies of rake, but only 1 rails.

```
xxxx@yyyy project-x % docker-compose run web whereis rails
[+] Running 1/0
 ⠿ Container project-x-db_1  Running                                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
rails: /usr/local/bundle/bin/rails
xxxx@yyyy project-x % docker-compose run web whereis rake
[+] Running 1/0
 ⠿ Container project-x-db_1  Running                                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
rake: /usr/local/bin/rake /usr/local/bundle/bin/rake
```

Comment: You've not installed the rails gem globally, try `bundle exec rails g`. You might have a different version of `rake` globally.

Comment: @Stivaros does not seem to be the issue, i tried bundle exec rails g, and it threw the same error. A new development is that I had a buddy try out my devfile and code on his WSL machine, and he didn't have this problem. I am checking if i have multiple rails binaries installed due to weird gemfile.

Comment: Mounting .:/app in your docker-compose.yaml for web means your overlaid all the changes you did in your Dockerfile's /app from your Docker host directory.

Not familiar with Rails, but does gem install dumps stuffs into your /app that you needed to get it running?

Comment: Changed the mount to /myapp, still having same issue. gem install will dump stuff into /usr/local/bundle/gems by default. I did a check, and the binaries seem to be in the right place. I am going to try deleting the lockfile and remaking it, see if it works, the lock file behaves much like how package-lock.json would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it.

I think the Gemfile.lock had conflicts on it that affected my container but not my buddy's.

I removed the Gemfile.lock and ran bundle install. This fixed the issue of rails g not working.

Would love to hear from a rails expert on why the bundle install did not make an entirely new lock file when run inside the container.